# Where to find search queries?

Tags: google-analytics

I am hoping to find the search queries that people use to find our website via search engines such as Bing, Yandex, Baidu, etc.

In Google Analytics, I went to Acquisition > Search Console > Queries. I saw a page of "This report requires Search Console integration to be enabled". Do I have to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you connect the Search Console to your Google Analytics Account you get the Google Search Data from Search Console shown in Analytics (only the data from google). You won´t see data from Bing, Yandex, etc.

You also don´t see conversion or behavioral metrics to this keywords. It looks like this (the same you see in the search console):
[image]

The connection is very easy: Admin >> (Select the right property) >> "All Products" (second column) >> scroll down to Search Console (the last one)

The reason, why you don´t see the keywords in Google Analytics is the Google Safe Search updtae (2011). Google changed the SERPs to https and webanalytics tools don´t get the keywords anymore. You just see (not provided).

There are some possible solutions to avoid this:

1. here are some workarounds you could use. For example
   https://blog.kissmetrics.com/unlock-keyword-not-provided/
2. There are some Tools like https://keyword-hero.com They provide you
   the keywords again in Analytics.